# Delivering Business Intelligence with Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Package Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm currently in Chapter 8 of Larson's work *Delivering Business Intelligence with Microsoft SQL Server 2012*

The book instructs me to build a SQL server 2012 Integration Services Package with a Data source based in SQL Server 2012 (ADO.NET, a database named MaxMinAccounting)  and another De-Normalized Data mart database named MaxMinManufacturingDM, being populated with the SQL Server Destination task.

Although I realize that the Import wizard offered in SQL Server 2012 could create this task for me, I think the book is trying to build the foundation for creating packages in the future as they become more complex. So I want to complete this task in SSIS.

In the Source ADO.NET task, I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT LocationCode As PlantNumber,
              LocationName as PlantName,
              CAST(CountryCode AS varchar(2)) AS CountryCode
FROM Locations
WHERE LOCATIONTYPE = 'Plant Site'
```

It appears that LocationCode is an INT, LocationName is a varchar(50) and countrycode is listed as an nchar(2)

In my destination table, DimPlant, I have three columns.
PlantNumber as an int, PlantName as a nvarchar(30) and countrycode as nvarchar(2)

At first I thought that the data types might not be mapping correctly since they are different. So I decided to use a cast statement to change the data types. Now when I run the package the entire thing errors out and SSIS doesn't give me any explanation at all about what is wrong. I'm frustrated and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: You need to increase size of PlantName column in DimPlant from `varchar (30)` to `varchar(50)`.

Comment: At least post the error. You as the developer need to make a decision about how you are going to fit a possible 50 characters of data into a field that is only 30 characters wide. You could truncate the last 20 characters and possibly lose data. Or you could error the package. Or you could extend the field in the target table. This is a real world scenario and in the real world you would either fix the target data type or truncate the characters.

Answer (score 0):

I elected to make the target DIM table a 50 character field. I also found that SSIS has this nasty habit of not cleaning up after itself if a table errors out. I find each Data Step I create usually has a corresponding `DELETE FROM (table Name)` associated with it in SSMS.

Thank you for your responses.